# Remove elements from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and learning about the lists. I am trying to create a function that will remove a specific value from the list. I know there is a `.remove()` function to remove elements but it doesn't work on the nested list.

```
def remove(list, x):
   if x in list:  
      return list.remove(x)

mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2],2] 
remove(mylist, 2) 
print(mylist)
```

The result I'd like to get:

```
[1, 3, 4, 8]
```

Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Can you include your desired output?

Comment: Why is your desired output not `[[1, 3, 4, 8]]`?

Comment: Is every element of the outer list either a list or an integer? Will there be only one level of nesting or an indefinite number of levels?

Comment: If you don't mind having nested list as output and also, there is only one level of nesting, then the following will work `newlist = [[i for i in x if i!=value_to_remove] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in mylist if x!=value_to_remove]`

Answer (score 4):

I customize your code here you can see an online version https://onlinegdb.com/Sk2oA9KGV

Continue and read the description if you don't understand

```
def remove(list, x):
       if x in list:  
          return list.remove(x)
          
    mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2],2]
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        
        if isinstance(mylist[i], list) == True : 
            mylist[i] = list(set(mylist[i]))
            mylist[i].remove(2)
            mylist[i].sort()
        else : 
            if mylist[i] == 2 : 
                del mylist[i]
    print(mylist)
    print()
```

the final result is like this

```
print(mylist)
```

> [[1, 3, 4, 8]]

```
print(mylist[0])
```

> [1, 3, 4, 8]

> **Complete description**

First of all, you need to use for loop to separate the arrays in a multidimensional array

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
```

Then you should check that the current variable that you have is `array` or not

```
if isinstance(mylist[i], list) == True :
```

If the condition being True then you continue
To remove duplicate items here `2` you need to this line

```
mylist[i] = list(set(mylist[i]))
```

And then run your remove funtion

```
mylist[i].remove(2)
```

After this, your result will be like this `[8, 1, 3, 4]`
Then you should sort your array by this code

```
mylist[i].sort()
```

And one more thing that if your variable was not arrayed you should check that if it is matched with your item that you want delete it or not if match then delete that

```
if mylist[i] == 2 : 
     del mylist[i]
```

Comment: Thank  you for your response but my list will be an input and cannot be a part of my function as it will change.

Comment: I do it according to your question, please add more details to update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear from your example whether you really want a flattened list as output or a you'd like to still keep the structure of your list. And also how many levels of nesting you will have. So I have written a recursive function which will remove item from a deeply nested list without flattening as well as flattening the output.

To make my solutions clear, I have modified your input list to the following.

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2],2,3,34,2,[[3,4],3,[1,2]]]
```

**Function**

```
def rem_list_item(l, remval, flatten=False):
    """Recursive function to remove an item from a nested list"""
    flatlist = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # Calling the function itself recursively if the item
            # is a list. 
            if flatten:
                # += will make sure the list is appended without nesting.
                flatlist+=rem_list_item(item, remval, flatten=True)
            else:
                # appended the sublist so that nesting is preserved
                flatlist.append(rem_list_item(item, remval, flatten=False))
        else:
            # If the item is not a list, just append it to the return list
            if item != remval:
                flatlist.append(item)
    return flatlist
```

**Without flattening**

```
rem_list_item(mylist, 2, flatten=False)
Out: [[1, 3, 4, 8], 3, 34, [[3, 4], 3, [1]]]
```

**With flattening**

```
rem_list_item(mylist, 2, flatten=True)
Out: [1, 3, 4, 8, 3, 34, 3, 4, 3, 1]
```